# Aligning label text inside an image in a proper way-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I want to write score inside of a box image.

First I placed the box in the place then I added score string above it using label like this.

```
private void drawScoreBoxes() {
    scoreImage = new Image(scoreTexture);
    stage.addActor(scoreImage);
    scoreImage.setPosition(UiConstants.BOX_POS_X,UiConstants.BOX_POS_Y2);
}

private void drawScore() {

        Label.LabelStyle scoreStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();// style
        scoreStyle.font = game.font2;
        scoreLabel2 = new Label(scoreController.getScoreString(), scoreStyle);// label
        scoreLabel2.setPosition(scoreImage.getX()+scoreImage.getWidth()/2,scoreImage.getY());       
    }
```

The score string should come exactly in the middle of the box image.In this case,when number of digit of score increases,string alignment is not proper.

How can I align it center always?

I found methods like getLabelAlign(),setAlignment(alignment) etc.
But I don't know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:
 1. Use TextButton:

```
Drawable scoreDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(scoreTexture));

TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle( scoreDrawable, scoreDrawable, scoreDrawable, font );

TextButton tb = new TextButton( scoreController.getScoreString() );

tb.setDisabled( true );
```

Or 2. Set Label bounds and align text:

```
    LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle( font, Color.BLACK );

    Label scoreLabel = new Label( scoreController.getScoreString(), labelStyle );

    scoreLabel.setBounds( scoreImage.getX(), scoreImage.getY(), scoreImage.getWidth(), scoreImage.getHeight() );

    scoreLabel.setAlignment( Align.center );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextButton](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#textbutton) instead of `Image` + `Label`

`TextButton` is a Button that contains `Label`, you can pass `Image` drawable part to Button that show as background part of your Label.

```
button = new TextButton("Button1", textButtonStyle);
stage.addActor(button);
```

A `TextButton` takes a string to render and a ButtonStyle, in this case a `TextButtonStyle`, which is basically a class that contains all the information about the button (font, drawable to render while not pressed, drawable to render while pressed etc).